# Format brackets in sublime text 2 to match their opening bracket

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

Say I have my SCSS file written like this, where all the brackets end on the same line:

```
.test{ color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
     .test2{ position: relative;
          .test3{ display: block }}}
```

Is there anyway to format just the closing brackets to something like this?

```
.test{ color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
     .test2{ position: relative;
          .test3{ display: block }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [CSSFormat](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSSFormat) by Package Control, and go to:

Edit -> CSS Format -> Compact(Break Selectors, No Spaces)